# How to get the key and pair value from json if the pair value as string

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Below is my json response

```
{
  "head": null,
  "body": {
    "8431073": "CN0028-00"
  },
  "responseTime": null,
  "leftPanel": null
}
```

I like to get the key and value from body. Below is my ajax call where i would like to take the key and value. but its returning empty value.

```
$.ajax({

  url: "ulhcircuit.json",
  method: "GET",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  success: function(data) {
    result = data.body;
    gethtmlvalues(result);
    $("#dialog_loading").hide();
  },
  fail: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
    console.log(xhr);
    $("#dialog_loading").hide();
  }
});


function gethtmlvalues(result) {
    var circuitList = result;
    var cktInstId = "";
    var cktName = "";
    if (circuitList != null) {

      if (circuitList.length > 0) {
        $.each(circuitList, function(key, value) {

          cktInstId = key; // returns empty values
          cktName = value; // returns empty values
        });
      }
    }
}
```

I would like to have the cktInstId  as 8431073 and cktName  as CN0028-00

Please help me.Thanks in advance

Comment: Please console.log(data.body) in ajax success event and check what you are getting?

Comment: as a object..If we click that object then it is showing as 8431073:"CN0028-00"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your response enters `gethtmlvalues`, you are passing `data.body`, which based on the JSON you've given looks like:

```
{ "8431073": "CN0028-00" }
```

This is a plain JS object, not a list, and existence of a `length` property doesn't mean amount of items it contains. This means you don't need the length check (you are comparing `undefined > 0`). You also don't need a (wrongly) named extra variable `circuitList`, you can just use `result`.

```
function gethtmlvalues(result){
  if(result != null){    
      $.each(result,function(key, value){
          console.log(key, value); // this will print your key value pair
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: @saminathan no problem mate, glad to help

Answer (score 0):

circuitList.length is not a property, use Object.keys(circuitList).length.

```js
var data = {"head": null,"body": {"8431073": "CN0028-00"},"responseTime": null,"leftPanel": null}

var result = data.body;
gethtmlvalues(result);


function gethtmlvalues(result){
debugger;
var circuitList = result;
var cktInstId = "";
var cktName = "";

  if(circuitList != null){    
    //if(circuitList.length > 0){
        $.each(circuitList,function(key, value){
            console.log(key);
            console.log(value);
            cktInstId = key; // returns empty values
            cktName = value; // returns empty values
        });
    //}
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```